# load() function won't allow scripts on page to execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php script which has a select box which allows user to filter some data.And I have used change event on select box to trigger jquery's load function to load a div of another page which will show that filtered data.Now the problem is I have a javascript function which is being called from that page upon some check in php , and this is resulting in that javascript function not getting called at all.Is there any work around in this scenario?I tried using $.get() but I'm not sure if it will allow me to load only part of page.

This is the load() function's call

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#topic-filter-select').on('change' , function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: templateUrl+"/ajax/custom_ajax_functions.php",
            data : {
                functionName : 'load_topic_filter',
                topic_id : e.target.value
            },
            success: function(result) {
                for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
                    result[i] = parseInt(result[i]);
                result = JSON.stringify(result);

                $('#activity-container').empty();
                $('#activity-container').load("/topic-filter-template?result="+result+" #topic-page");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                $('#post-0').empty();
                $('#post-0').append("<div id='filtered-activities'><h4>Something went wrong , please try again.</h4></div>");
            }
        });
     });
 });
```

And the php check which gives call to javascript function is

```
<?php $result = has_user_voted($poll_id , $current_user_id);?>      
<?php if($result[0] == true) :?>
  <?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">animatePollEffect('.json_encode($result).','.$poll->ID.')</script>';?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: [Read how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

there your question and code snippet creating a lots of confusion. Please, correct it properly to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: My problem is I am loading a page ( Snippet no 2 ) using load()  ( snippet no 1 ).I have a js function call in (Snippet no 2) animatePollEffect which is not getting called when used with load().